# Programs using CUDA freeze after one of them fails, can't be killed

Tags: nvidia, kill, freeze, cuda

I'm trying to debug a certain [program](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/blob/graph_support/examples/modified_cuda_samples/simpleCudaGraphs/simpleCudaGraphs.cu) of mine which uses CUDA (specifically, CUDA graphs). This program (sometimes) triggers an error, then dies - relatively gracefully. However, after it has failed, when I try to run any other programs using the GPU - they hang immediately as they start - and can't be killed, even with `kill -KILL` by root.

Looking in my dmesg output (this is a Linux machine), I see the following trailing lines:

```
[  155.786155] nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols nvUvmInterfaceDisableAccessCntr from proprietary module nvidia, inheriting taint.
[  155.813728] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 236.
[  209.863685] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:01:00: GPU-82f73d0a-cec0-ed8b-f7da-e87d7ed83f69
[  209.863689] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 31, pid=2823, name=simpleCudaGraph, Ch 00000010, intr 10000000. MMU Fault: ENGINE GRAPHICS GPCCLIENT_T1_0 faulted @ 0x7fcb_83c00000. Fault is of type FAULT_PDE ACCESS_TYPE_READ
[  225.483961] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 31, pid=3114, name=simpleCudaGraph, Ch 00000010, intr 10000000. MMU Fault: ENGINE GRAPHICS GPCCLIENT_T1_0 faulted @ 0x7f3e_d5c00000. Fault is of type FAULT_PDE ACCESS_TYPE_READ
```

What's going on?

Some information about my system: Devuan Daedalus, kernel 6.1.20-1 . CPU is Intel i5 7600K. If any other information might be useful, please ask and I'll add it.